# php Curl error: Failure when receiving data from the peer

Tags: php, curl

I had a basic Curl script which basically executed a script on remote server.
I was working fine from around 6 months.

Yesterday it stopped working, and was giving back following error.

> Curl error: Failure when receiving data from the peer

Would like to know if anyone knows on which condition the curl would returned such error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When dealing with problem with curl, run it again with:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR,  fopen('php://output', 'w'));
```

Usually the exact error message is in there somewhere.

*Fixed*: `CURLOPT_STDERR` indeed needs a stream resource as @Lübnah states in the comments, and @Roman tried to edit in (although earlier reviewers denied the edit, I've now included it in the answer).

Comment: I am already doing your suggestion, and it gives me the error which I mentioned above. Error code : 56. 
And error printed out in file is : Failure when receiving data from the peer. 
Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: Sounds like a TCP problem. What happens if you increase the timeout> And are you sending more headers the just a GET / POST? (i.e. host etc.)? If not, what happens if you add them, and vice-versa?

Comment: I had to change the 2nd line to `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('php://output', 'w'));` before this worked for me.